# What is the flow process for 2 Factor Authentication and the use of the "secret key" in a c# app?

Tags: c#, google-oauth

Is there a flow process for 2 factor Authentication that explains the process.
Google Authenticator is used here.

For example ,

```
 1. user is configured to use 2 Factor Authentication.
 2. user logins in with username and password.
 3.if successful then a QR screen is displayed for the user to enter code.
 4.on submit the code the user is redirected to teh app and the code is verified.
 5.if successful , user is allowed in.
```

What i dont get is the use of the "secret" and how it is used , where is it stored ?

So in between steps 2 and 3 I assume there must be something in the background that happens in order to generate the one time code , which I am trying to get a grip of in regards to a c# sample app .

Any ideas if there is a sample app that can help with this.

Comment: I think it's a simple concept like when you get token form Oauth or something
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc


>What i dont get is the use of the "secret" and how it is used 
- The use of the secret is to give to the client for use as another factor to authentication  

> where is it stored ?  
It may be store or not store as per provider implement (may be just only a message that the provider can understand ). The real goal is for client to show it to proof that  you is really the real client.

Comment: Imagine you to the club the you show guard your member card , the guard said ok you have a club card then if you are the real member you must know what the word in sms that I gonna send you the  to your mobile ( number that is in your club card)  , then you look at your mobile , show to message to the guard.

Comment: Is there a c# example using Google authenticator ?

Comment: sorry,I don't know which are the best practice.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

https://github.com/BrandonPotter/GoogleAuthenticator

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421950/is-there-a-tutorial-on-how-to-implement-google-authenticator-in-net-apps